# Belongs on stackoverflow close reason

Tags: feature-request, migration

I currently only see belongs on meta.cs close reason, when you choose to close as off-topic. Is it possible to add stackoverflow to it?

Comment: +1 I have felt the need for this several times. Would be nice to have that option.

Comment: or in general: "Fits better at a different SE forum", with a place to write which one..

Comment: @RanG.: I was under the impression that if it gets closed with belongs on stackoverflow, it will get auto-migrated. Is the not true?

Comment: I think there should be a feature that allows users to vote for migration (and not only to close).

Comment: math.stackexchange can also be added to this list.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus math and cstheory.  I also think codereview and programmers in addition  are good alternatives to the "programming related questions belong to SO".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Migration paths are normally not created from or to beta sites (there can be exceptions if we demonstrate an evident need). You can always flag to request a migration.

In the last 90 days, we only migrated 13 questions away to SO. 2 of these were rejected (i.e. subsequently closed on the target site), 1 rightly (in my opinion as an SO user), 1 because the asker deleted his own question. So we have a good success rate for migrations (I do sometimes filter by closing as straight off-topic questions that were flagged for migration but I think will get shot down as low quality on SO).

On the other hand, barely more than 1 question per week is not enough to create a migration path. When the figure gets to 1 per day, maybe. For the time being, keep flagging.

Do note that sometimes people ask very low-quality programming questions (e.g. a code dump and no more information than “it doesnt work”). We don't want to migrate these. Sometimes they ask on CS or other vaguely programming-related sites because they've been blocked on SO for posting too many low-quality questions — in those cases, even if we do migrate, the migration is automatically rejected (it shows in the question history as closed, locked, unlocked in quick succession).

Answer (score 3):

Migration is mod-only on beta sites since Oversight has decided that beta sites should not migrate away, but close on site in order to shape the profile of the site in a visible way.

We have been migrating some questions because

- because we think we know our scope well enough and
- because of the amount of clear mispostings of SO-questions.

Comment: While there are normally no migration paths from or to beta sites, I know of at least one exception. I'm not sure if CS → SO should be a non-mod migration path right now, but I think CSTheory → CS would make sense.